# Send json data into a php variable to be used in javascript

Tags: php, json

I'm quite new to php and don't actually know if this is possible

Im currently outputting JSON code with php using the following code

```
echo  json_encode($output, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

But what I want to do is have the above data inside a variable.

I tried

```
$JSONDATAX = json_encode($output, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

But it doesn't seem to like it when I call $JSONDATAX.

The original echo way works completely fine.

edit ........

```
      $lrs = CDB::ExecuteQuery($sql);

            if($lrs) {
    $jsonData = convert($lrs);
}



function convert($lrs) {

    $intermediate = array();

      while ($vals = CDB::GetAssoc($lrs))  {
        $key = $vals['POS'];
        $x = $vals['CODE'];
        $y = $vals['COUNT'];
        $intermediate[$key][] = array('x' => $x, 'y' => $y);
    }


   $output = array();

    foreach($intermediate as $key => $values) {
        $output[] = array(
            "key" => $key,
            'values' => $values
        );
    }

  $data1 = json_encode($output, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);


}










?>
<script>

 var negative_test_data = <?php echo $data1; ?>;

var chart;
nv.addGraph(function() {
    chart = nv.models.multiBarChart()
    .color(d3.scale.category10().range())
      .rotateLabels(0)      //Angle to rotate x-axis labels.
      .transitionDuration(300)
       .showControls(true)   //Allow user to switch between 'Grouped' and 'Stacked' mode.
      .groupSpacing(0.24)    //Distance between each group of bars.

      ;
```

As you can see, I am using php just after var negative_test_data , but it doesn't produce anything.

Comment: If you do a `print_r($output)` do you get an array back?

Comment: Can you show the code when you try to "echo" ?

Comment: I get an array back with the code above by echoing it, and this works fine with the chart i'm using. but I'm trying to say if I try make it a variable, it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you closing the `script` tag?

Comment: this is just a snippet of my code, yes it has a closing script tag, but thats nothing to do with what I'm asking

Comment: Have you checked if there are any JSON errors? [`json_last_error_msg`](http://php.net/json_last_error_msg)

Comment: Echoing it? If you echo an array you don't get much back.

Comment: Yes, it will be an array. You can call elements by like negative_test_data['{key}'], I think.

You're not showing how you display the negative_test_data so I'm just guessing it's wrong

Comment: I don't think I've explained this very well, I will edit post.

Comment: Are you getting an error? (hint: ini_set('display_errors', true) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your edited example, $data is a local variable inside the convert function, so it cannot be accessed outside that function. the result of json_encode should be returned:

```
$data1 = json_encode($output, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

should be

```
return json_encode($output, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Then, the result of the convert function can be echoed:

```
var negative_test_data = <?php echo $data1; ?>;
```

should be

```
var negative_test_data = <?php echo convert($lrs); ?>;
```

(There should probably be a an additional if around that whole  part, depending on what you want to happen when $lrs does not evaluate to true)

Comment: - Thanks for the answer man, worked a treat! Although I had to do var negative_test_data = <?php echo convert($jsonData); ?>; rather than $lrs

Answer (score 0):

This should be all you really need:

```
$phpvar = json_encode($output);
echo "<script>var negative_test_data = {$phpvar};</script>";
```

Comment: i used, $phpvar = json_encode($output, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
 and inside my <script> tags <?PHP echo "var negative_test_data = {$phpvar};";  ?> It didn't bring anything back, just blank.

Comment: then do a `var_dump($phpvar)`. if it says boolean false, then the json encoding failed, and you need to check json_last_error()